# PDF PROBLEM when exporting Mathematica code

Tags: plotting, export, pdf-format

I am always running into the problem that my figures are cut-off when I export my entire mathematica notebook as a PDF.

[image]

Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Have you tried `ImageSize -> Full` option?

Comment: @Shadowray can you provide an example, please ?

Comment: @DoHe for example, `GraphicsGrid[{{Plot[x^2, {x, -1, 1}], Plot[Sin[x], {x, -1, 1}]}}, ImageSize -> Full]`

Comment: @Shadowray I will try that. Thanks